# How to dynamically add form elements with a value="" instead of it equaling the last form element

Tags: jquery

I have my form elements here:

```
<li><div id="formanswer1" class="clonedInput">Answer:
<input type="text" id="formanswer1" value="" /></div></li>

<li><input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add Answer" /></li>
<li><input type="button" id="btnDel" value="Remove Answer" /></li>
```

and my jquery code here:

```
        $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','disabled');
        $('#btnAdd').click(function() {
        var num     = $('.clonedInput').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
        var newNum  = new Number(num + 1);      // the numeric ID of the new input field being added

        // create the new element via clone(), and manipulate it's ID using newNum value
        var newElem = $('#formanswer' + num).clone().attr('id', 'formanswer' + newNum);
        var guianswer = $('#guianswer'+num).clone().attr('id', 'guianswer' + newNum).html('Answer '+newNum);

        // manipulate the name/id values of the input inside the new element
        newElem.children(':first').attr('id', 'formanswer' + newNum);
        guianswer.children(':first').attr('id', 'guianswer' + newNum).attr('name', 'guianswer' + newNum);

        // insert the new element after the last "duplicatable" input field
        $('#formanswer' + num).after(newElem);
        $('#guianswer' + num).after(guianswer);

        // enable the "remove" button
        $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','');

        // business rule: you can only add 5 questions
        if (newNum == 5)
            $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','disabled');
    });

    $('#btnDel').click(function() {
        var num = $('.clonedInput').length;
        $('#formanswer' + num).remove();

        $('#guianswer'+num).remove();

        // enable the "add" button
        $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','');

        // if only one element remains, disable the "remove" button
        if (num-1 == 1)
            $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','disabled');
    });
```

I have a jsfiddle here: [JsFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/wmGPz/1/)

Basically what is happening is when i add new input using the button it copies the previous inputs value.
 Example: in input 1 if i enter "abc" then push add button a new input appears with value"abc" when i want a value "" blank or no value.

ANY and ALL help is much appreciated!

Comment: Warning, you have two html element with the same id (formanswer1), I think that one of them should be guianswer1  instead.

Comment: @Nettogrof good catch, OP you should fix this ID's need to be different in the dom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change this line to clear the value.

```
      newElem.children(':first').attr('id', 'formanswer' + newNum).val('');
```

Comment: im embarrassed now. i was trying to change the value through the attr().  :(  thx very much

Comment: no worries just bookmark api.jquery.com always a good place to search for answers.